# Half brother, step brother, or no term

Tags: kinship-terminology

I was married before and had 3 children.  My wife and I got divorced and have since remarried other people. My new wife and I had a son together and my ex wife and her new husband  had a son. These two young boys will be only related by their older siblings. Is there a name for what they are? I've searched the web but cannot find a term

Comment: Welcome to GFH SE!  I normally go to http://stevemorse.org/relation/calculator.html to look for terms that might apply but that provides no option to insert ex-spouses that arise from divorce.

Answer (score 3):

Since there is no blood/genetic relation between such siblings of half-siblings, there may not be an official term. Unofficially people sometimes refer to them as cross siblings which I believe is a play on cross cousins, which is an official genetic term.

Comment: Although I had never seen the term before this answer, the wikipedia article on "Siblings" includes a section on cross siblings [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sibling#Cross_siblings ]. Whatever the derivation, the label will gain currency, as these relationships become more frequent.